# Using count if with dates

Tags: excel, countif, vba

I am trying to count how many dates in the G column (or even better: column with the header "document date") are:

- 3 workdays old or less
- between 3 and 30 workdays
- over 30 workdays

These are formulas that I use in excel but I would like to do it with just one click because the excel file is a download from SAP and each day new download is performed.

```
=COUNTIF(G:G, ">=" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-2)

=COUNTIF(G:G,"<=" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-3) - COUNTIF(G:G, "<=" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)

=COUNTIF(G:G, "<=" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)
```

I am new with VBA and can't really translate it to vba code.

Hope you can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in VBA the formulas should be

```
=COUNTIF(G:G, "">="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-2)
=COUNTIF(G:G,""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-3) - COUNTIF(G:G, ""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)
=COUNTIF(G:G, ""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)
```

For example if you want the formulas to be in H1, H2 & H3 cells then VBA code will be

```
Cells(1, 8).Value = "=COUNTIF(G:G, "">="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-2)"
Cells(2, 8).Value = "=COUNTIF(G:G,""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-3) - COUNTIF(G:G, ""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)"
Cells(3, 8).Value = "=COUNTIF(G:G, ""<="" & WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)-30)"
```